# My collision detection code gives incorrect result

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, separating-axis-theorem

I am trying to use Separating Axis Theorem to check for collision between two shapes, but it's not working correctly. It's giving all incorrect results. The problem is in the collision-checking function. Is there something wrong in calculating the projection-overlap ?

This is my collision-checking function :-

```
function collisionCheck() {
    /* getting all the axes from both shapes */
    var axes = [];
    for(var i=0; i<shape1.vertices.length; i++) {
        var v1 = shape1.vertices[i];
        var v2 = [];
        if(i < shape1.vertices.length-1) {
            v2 = shape1.vertices[i+1];
        }
        else {
            v2 = shape1.vertices[0];
        }
        var edge = [v2[0]-v1[0], v2[1]-v1[1]];
        var normal = [-edge[1], edge[0]];
        var mag = Math.sqrt(normal[0]*normal[0] + normal[1]*normal[1]);
        var unit = [normal[0]/mag, normal[1]/mag];
        axes.push(unit);
    }
    for(var i=0; i<shape2.vertices.length; i++) {
        var v1 = shape2.vertices[i];
        var v2 = [];
        if(i < shape2.vertices.length-1) {
            v2 = shape2.vertices[i+1];
        }
        else {
            v2 = shape2.vertices[0];
        }
        var edge = [v2[0]-v1[0], v2[1]-v1[1]];
        var normal = [-edge[1], edge[0]];
        var mag = Math.sqrt(normal[0]*normal[0] + normal[1]*normal[1]);
        var unit = [normal[0]/mag, normal[1]/mag];
        axes.push(unit);
    }
    /* projecting both shapes onto each axes */
    for(var i=0; i<axes.length; i++) {
        var axis = axes[i];
        // projecting shape 1
        var min = Infinity;
        var max = -Infinity;
        for(var j=0; j<shape1.vertices.length; j++) {
            var vertex = shape1.vertices[j];
            var proj = axis[0]*vertex[0] + axis[1]*vertex[1];
            if(proj < min) {
                min = proj;
            }
            else if(proj > max) {
                max = proj;
            }
        }
        var projection1 = [min, max];
        // projecting shape 2
        var min = Infinity;
        var max = -Infinity;
        for(var j=0; j<shape2.vertices.length; j++) {
            var vertex = shape2.vertices[j];
            var proj = axis[0]*vertex[0] + axis[1]*vertex[1];
            if(proj < min) {
                min = proj;
            }
            else if(proj > max) {
                max = proj;
            }
        }
        var projection2 = [min, max];
        if(projection1[1] > projection2[0] && projection1[0] < projection2[0]) {

        }
        else if(projection2[1] > projection1[0] && projection2[0] < projection1[0]) {

        }
        else { 
            return false; // return false if projections not overlapping on any one axis
        }
    }
    return true; // return true if projections is overlapping on all the axes
};
```

Here is what's happening :-

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Separating Axis Theorem</title>
  <script>
   var canvas = null;
   var canvas2d = null;
   var lastTime = null;
   var leftKey = null;
   var rightKey = null;
   var upKey = null;
   var downKey = null;
   var aKey = null;
   var dKey = null;
   var wKey = null;
   var sKey = null;
   var text = "";

   var shape1 = {
    vertices: [],
    draw: function(canvas2d) {
     canvas2d.beginPath();
     var v1 = this.vertices[0];
     canvas2d.moveTo(v1[0], v1[1]);
     for(var i=1; i<this.vertices.length; i++) {
      var v = this.vertices[i];
      canvas2d.lineTo(v[0], v[1]);
     }
     canvas2d.closePath();
     canvas2d.strokeStyle = "red";
     canvas2d.stroke();
    },
    update: function(delta, leftKey, rightKey, upKey, downKey) {
     var dx = 0;
     var dy = 0;
     var dxValue = 0.3;
     var dyValue = 0.3;
     if(leftKey) {
      dx = -dxValue;
     }
     if(rightKey) {
      dx = dxValue;
     }
     if(!leftKey && !rightKey) {
      dx = 0;
     }
     if(upKey) {
      dy = -dyValue;
     }
     if(downKey) {
      dy = dyValue;
     }
     if(!upKey && !downKey) {
      dy = 0;
     }
     for(var i=0; i<this.vertices.length; i++) {
      var v = this.vertices[i];
      v = [v[0]+(dx*delta), v[1]+(dy*delta)];
      this.vertices[i] = v;
     }
    },
    initialize: function() {
     this.vertices.push([100, 100], [250, 150], [220, 250], [120, 230]);
    }
   };

   var shape2 = {
    vertices: [],
    draw: function(canvas2d) {
     canvas2d.beginPath();
     var v1 = this.vertices[0];
     canvas2d.moveTo(v1[0], v1[1]);
     for(var i=1; i<this.vertices.length; i++) {
      var v = this.vertices[i];
      canvas2d.lineTo(v[0], v[1]);
     }
     canvas2d.closePath();
     canvas2d.strokeStyle = "green";
     canvas2d.stroke();
    },
    update: function(delta, aKey, dKey, wKey, sKey) {
     var dx = 0;
     var dy = 0;
     var dxValue = 0.3;
     var dyValue = 0.3;
     if(aKey) {
      dx = -dxValue;
     }
     if(dKey) {
      dx = dxValue;
     }
     if(!aKey && !dKey) {
      dx = 0;
     }
     if(wKey) {
      dy = -dyValue;
     }
     if(sKey) {
      dy = dyValue;
     }
     if(!wKey && !sKey) {
      dy = 0;
     }
     for(var i=0; i<this.vertices.length; i++) {
      var v = this.vertices[i];
      v = [v[0]+(dx*delta), v[1]+(dy*delta)];
      this.vertices[i] = v;
     }
    },
    initialize: function() {
     this.vertices.push([400, 200], [500, 200], [480, 300], [400, 280]);
    }
   };

   function initialize() {
    lastTime = new Date().getTime();
    leftKey = false;
    rightKey = false;
    upKey = false;
    downKey = false;
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas2d = canvas.getContext("2d");
    window.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpListener, false);
    window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownListener, false);
    shape1.initialize();
    shape2.initialize();
    gameLoop();
   };

   function gameLoop() {
    window.clearTimeout();
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    var delta = currentTime - lastTime;
    lastTime = currentTime;
    draw();
    update(delta);
    var difference = new Date().getTime() - currentTime;
    window.setTimeout(gameLoop, 1000/60-difference);
   };

   function draw() {
    canvas2d.fillStyle = "black";
    canvas2d.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    shape1.draw(canvas2d);
    shape2.draw(canvas2d);
    canvas2d.font = "25px Arial";
    canvas2d.fillStyle = "yellow";
    canvas2d.fillText("use W, A, S, D keys to move green box", 30, 430);
    canvas2d.fillText("use A, S, D, F keys to move red box", 30, 460);
    canvas2d.fillStyle = "rgba(100, 255, 100, 1)";
    canvas2d.fillText(text, 30, 30);
   };

   function update(deltaVal) {
    var delta = deltaVal;
    if(delta > 50) {
     delta = 50;
    }
    shape1.update(delta, leftKey, rightKey, upKey, downKey);
    shape2.update(delta, aKey, dKey, wKey, sKey);
    if(collisionCheck()) {
     text = "Intersecting";
    }
    else {
     text = "Not intersecting";
    }
   };

   function keyUpListener(e) {
    if(e.which === 37) {
     leftKey = false;
    }
    else if(e.which === 39) {
     rightKey = false;
    }
    else if(e.which === 38) {
     upKey = false;
    }
    else if(e.which === 40) {
     downKey = false;
    }
    if(e.which === 65) {
     aKey = false;
    }
    else if(e.which === 68) {
     dKey = false;
    }
    else if(e.which === 87) {
     wKey = false;
    }
    else if(e.which === 83) {
     sKey = false;
    }
   };

   function keyDownListener(e) {
    if(e.which === 37) {
     leftKey = true;
    }
    else if(e.which === 39) {
     rightKey = true;
    }
    else if(e.which === 38) {
     upKey = true;
    }
    else if(e.which === 40) {
     downKey = true;
    }
    if(e.which === 65) {
     aKey = true;
    }
    else if(e.which === 68) {
     dKey = true;
    }
    else if(e.which === 87) {
     wKey = true;
    }
    else if(e.which === 83) {
     sKey = true;
    }
   };

   function collisionCheck() {
    /* getting all the axes from both shapes */
    var axes = [];
    for(var i=0; i<shape1.vertices.length; i++) {
     var v1 = shape1.vertices[i];
     var v2 = [];
     if(i < shape1.vertices.length-1) {
      v2 = shape1.vertices[i+1];
     }
     else {
      v2 = shape1.vertices[0];
     }
     var edge = [v2[0]-v1[0], v2[1]-v1[1]];
     var normal = [-edge[1], edge[0]];
     var mag = Math.sqrt(normal[0]*normal[0] + normal[1]*normal[1]);
     var unit = [normal[0]/mag, normal[1]/mag];
     axes.push(unit);
    }
    for(var i=0; i<shape2.vertices.length; i++) {
     var v1 = shape2.vertices[i];
     var v2 = [];
     if(i < shape2.vertices.length-1) {
      v2 = shape2.vertices[i+1];
     }
     else {
      v2 = shape2.vertices[0];
     }
     var edge = [v2[0]-v1[0], v2[1]-v1[1]];
     var normal = [-edge[1], edge[0]];
     var mag = Math.sqrt(normal[0]*normal[0] + normal[1]*normal[1]);
     var unit = [normal[0]/mag, normal[1]/mag];
     axes.push(unit);
    }
    /* projecting both shapes onto each axes */
    for(var i=0; i<axes.length; i++) {
     var axis = axes[i];
     // projecting shape 1
     var min = Infinity;
     var max = -Infinity;
     for(var j=0; j<shape1.vertices.length; j++) {
      var vertex = shape1.vertices[j];
      var proj = axis[0]*vertex[0] + axis[1]*vertex[1];
      if(proj < min) {
       min = proj;
      }
      else if(proj > max) {
       max = proj;
      }
     }
     var projection1 = [min, max];
     // projecting shape 2
     var min = Infinity;
     var max = -Infinity;
     for(var j=0; j<shape2.vertices.length; j++) {
      var vertex = shape2.vertices[j];
      var proj = axis[0]*vertex[0] + axis[1]*vertex[1];
      if(proj < min) {
       min = proj;
      }
      else if(proj > max) {
       max = proj;
      }
     }
     var projection2 = [min, max];
     if(projection1[1] > projection2[0] && projection1[0] < projection2[0]) {
      
     }
     else if(projection2[1] > projection1[0] && projection2[0] < projection1[0]) {
      
     }
     else { 
      return false; // return false if projections not overlapping on any one axis
     }
    }
    return true; // return true if projections is overlapping on all the axes
   };

   window.addEventListener("load", initialize, false);
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id = "canvas" width = "640" height = "480"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Raj. By not getting the right answer what do you mean? Is there a particular angle or situation where the collision isn't valid, or is it just not registering them at all? If there's a specific scenario then it might help us spot the discrepancy.

Comment: @Huxellberget oh okey, I will edit the question.

Comment: Question edited. Added html snippet. Run the app. You'll see the results are incorrect.